# Pass a user to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

OK, a little stuck here.

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class UserProfileEdit
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [Required]            
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string TwitterHandle{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // etc etc
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult YourProfile()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;           

    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

    // Construct the viewmodel
    UserProfileEdit model = new UserProfileEdit();            
   model.ApplicationUser = user;

     return View(model); 
}
```

And on the View I have @model `MySite.Models.UserProfileEdit` at the top.

How can I pass the user to the ViewModel? I know I can do it line by line

```
model.Email = user.Email;
```

for example, but it should be simpler?

Comment: You could use a tool such as [automapper](http://automapper.org/). One way or the other you need to map the properties. (and your view model should not contain a property `ApplicationUser` if it contains properties for editing/displaying each value of `ApplicationUser`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I can map one by one. model.Email = user.Email; etc. But this seems error prone and fiddly. I thought there should be some magic way to pass the user to the VM and Hey Presto.

Comment: if you have same field in model and user, then you must not repeat of fields in model as its duplicated. and try to use directly user object of model wherever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to do what you want to do.

You can use a tool, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Or you can pass data by a constructor :

```
public class UserProfileEdit
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        [Required]            
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string TwitterHandle{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // etc etc

        public UserProfileEdit() {}

        public UserProfileEdit(ApplicationUser user) {
              this.ApplicationUser = user;
              this.Email = user.Email;
              // ...
        }

}

 public ActionResult YourProfile()
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;           

            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

             return View(new UserProfileEdit(user)); 
        }
```

Or using a method to init your view model's data :

```
public class UserProfileEdit
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        [Required]            
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string TwitterHandle{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // etc etc

        public void Init(ApplicationUser user) {
              this.ApplicationUser = user;
              this.Email = user.Email;
              // do what you want to do
        }

}

 public ActionResult YourProfile()
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;           

            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
            UserProfileEdit vm = new UserProfileEdit();
            vm.Init(user);

             return View(vm); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting and more along the lines of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it line by line, or you can use AutoMapper. Give it a try http://automapper.org/

This is very useful specially when you have the same kind of object mappings repeated in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll just stick with doing it line by line.

Comment: You should at least wrap it inside a function, don't simply put all the lines there, I guess...